# Use ppcrossarm to cross compile to Android?

Tags: android, freepascal

how can I use ppcrossarm to cross compile a Free Pascal file to Android?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the correct ppcrossarm (it could be for any arm)
2. Make sure you have the correct binutils installed and that the compiler can find them.

then basically

fpc -Tlinux -Parm file.pas

See also the buildfaq, http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf

Comment: Note that this is outdated. See recent maillist archives, a branch with android as a target separate from linux is being tested.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ARM compilers provided at freepascal.org only supports:

- Game Boy Advance
- Nintendo DS
- Linux
- Windows CE

which means you can probably only find ppcrossarm files for these four platform.

I did successfully compiled a few exe files for my Windows Phone, and perfectly executed. But, you may need other tools to link the .o file into an Android executable, not WinCE exe.